# Need some help expressing this as a series, if possible

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

Okay, so I'm working on a question, and after a bunch of simplification and manipulations, I get the following expression. Just wanted to ask if there's any way I can get this in the form of a series, with $n$ going from 0 to $\infty$. a is a random positive integer here.

$$
U(x) = Q\bigg[1 - \frac{a(a+1)}{2!}x^2 + \frac{a(a+1)(a+2)(a+3)}{4!}x^4 + ...\bigg] 
+ R\bigg[x - \frac{(a-1)(a+2)}{3!}x^3 + \frac{(a-1)(a+2)(a-3)(a+4)}{5!}x^5 + ...\bigg]
$$

I'm having trouble trying to figure out a way to simplify this further, so I'm just curious if it's possible. If not, then that's okay too.

Thanks for taking the time to look at this!!

Editing to add the DE I was working on:
$$(1-x^2)U''(x) -2xU'(x) +a(a+1)U(x) = 0$$

Comment: Why don't you write  the general terms ?

Comment: Please, give me the ODE as it was given to you

Comment: Added above ^^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*This is just for your curiosity*

$U(x)$ is already expressed as a linear combination of two Taylor series (for which you give only the first terms but in which the patterns of the coefficients is quite clear). I suppose that this is the power series solution of a second oreder differential equation which could be intresting to know.

So, what I think is that the problem would better be to find the analytic functions to which correspond these Taylor series.

The first one is "amazing" since it seems that we have
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac {c_n}{(2n)!} x^{2n}\quad \text{with} \quad c_n=\prod_{i=0}^{2n-1} (a+i)=a \,(a+1)_{2 n-1}$$ where appear Pochhammer symbols. This makes
$$f(x)=\, _2F_1\left(\frac{a}{2},\frac{a+1}{2};\frac{1}{2};-x^2\right)$$ where appears the gaussian hypergeometric function. But, guess what ?
$$\color{blue}{f(x)=\left(1+x^2\right)^{-\frac a2} \cos \left(a \tan ^{-1}(x)\right)}$$

For the second series, it seems to be much more complex since we have
$$g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac {d_n}{(2n+1)!} x^{2n+1}$$ with
$$d_n=\Bigg[\prod_{i=0}^{n} (a+2i)\Bigg]\,\,  \Bigg[\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (a+2i-1)\Bigg]=(-1)^{n+1}(a-1)  2^{2 n-1} \left(\frac{3-a}{2}\right)_{n-1}   \left(\frac{a+2}{2}\right)_n$$
$$\color{blue}{g(x)=x \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1-a}{2},\frac{a+2}{2};\frac{3}{2};x^2\right)}$$ which, unfortunately, does not simplify but explains why was required a power series solution.

For integer values of $a$, we have quite nice and simple expressions
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a & \left(x^2+1\right)^a\,f(x) \\
 1 & 1 \\
 2 & 1-x^2 \\
 3 & 1-3 x^2 \\
 4 & x^4-6 x^2+1 \\
 5 & 5 x^4-10 x^2+1 \\
 6 & -x^6+15 x^4-15 x^2+1 
\end{array}
\right)$$

For $g(x)$, it is a bit more complex but it write
$$g(x)= x Q(x)+ R(x) \tanh^{-1}(x)$$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
a & Q(x) & R(x) \\
 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 2 & \frac{3}{4} & -\frac{3 x^2}{4}+\frac{1}{4} \\
 3 & -\frac{5 x^2}{3}+1 & 0 \\
 4 & -\frac{105 x^2}{64}+\frac{55}{64} & \frac{105 x^4}{64}-\frac{45
   x^2}{32}+\frac{9}{64} \\
 5 & \frac{21 x^4}{5}-\frac{14 x^2}{3}+1 & 0 \\
 6 & \frac{1155 x^4}{256}-\frac{595 x^2}{128}+\frac{231}{256} & -\frac{1155
   x^6}{256}+\frac{1575 x^4}{256}-\frac{525 x^2}{256}+\frac{25}{256}
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Okay wow this is amazing. Yeah, so this was the power series solution for an ODE lol so you've got that right. But wow. I had honestly never heard of a Pochhammer symbol, nor have I ever used the hypergeometric function, but this is genuinely the coolest thing I've seen in a while, so thank you for this! Any suggestions on where I could learn more about these functions and where they pop up? It's absolutely crazy to me every time I find out how many more things there are that I just don't know. Also, thank you again, this. Is honestly so so cool!!

Comment: @Applesauce44. You will find everything on Internet (just google for these).  Pochhamer symbols are related to factorials  https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PochhammerSymbol.html  and for the specific  gaussian hypergeometric function  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function    Could you post the ODE in the question ? Cheers :-)

Comment: Thanks! And yeah sure, it was a legendre DE I believe.